# Can I ask for help in identifying an old video posted on the internet?

Tags: discussion, scope

It would been a "meme" or viral video by today's standards, but I vaguely remember it from back when YouTube was first gaining traction.

It isn't really a "Movie" and it would never have been on "TV" (that I know of)

Can I ask for help in finding it (*or the title of it*) here?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd be inclined to say no for a few reasons.

1. Music videos and commercials are specifically out of scope per the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I would lump random YouTube/Internet videos in that same general category.
2. The community appears to be trending away from accepting [identify-x](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-x) questions per other Meta posts like [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1987/26325).
3. Meme videos are endlessly derivative. You might want help identifying the [Star Wars Kid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPPj6viIBmU), but you saw version X and I'm describing version Y. The general description matches each time, but you never get what you want because I can't find the exact version you want.

That being said I think there is some gray area with some Internet videos.

Personally I would say popular web series like [Red vs. Blue](http://roosterteeth.com/show/red-vs-blue) would be on topic for identification/questions in my opinion however because there is a continuity, and the series does loosely emulate a narrative comedic TV show.

I would call other popular web based series like [Strong Bad](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail.html) and/or [Funny or Die](http://www.funnyordie.com/) off topic for identify questions, and information questions. The clips are generally short and stand alone. Similarly I think [identify-this-episode](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-episode) questions are off topic for TV shows like [America's Funniest Home Video](http://afv.com/), or [The Price Is Right](http://www.priceisright.com/) for the same reason.

---

I purposefully chose older references here because the OP was talking about an older Internet video.

Comment: Disappointing, but certainly understandable.

Comment: Regarding Red v. Blue: they have seasons, and I can buy the discs for each season the same way I can buy the discs for a season of e.g. The Simpsons. They may not be on broadcast TV, but they essentially work the same way.